# How busy is the E50/D1 motorway in Czech Republic?

Tags: driving, event-based-effects, czech-republic

According to Google maps there is road work on E50 from Prague to Brno.
We are going to drive that route next week, how bad is it?
Would it be better to take a different route? Google maps also show road work on road 12.

Anyone that has any information about the route Prague -> Brno.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are numerous cameras along the D1 motorway, all of which are [available online](http://www.dopravainformace.cz/dopravni-kamery.aspx?d=1). There are indeed roadworks on the approach to Brno, but you should be fine outside the peak hours:

[image]

Assuming you don't drive between 07:00-10:00 or 16:00-19:00 on weekdays, I'd take the D1.

Comment: Sweet! Thank you! I think we need to drive from Prague about 10:00, but we can just drive an hour earlier to compensate for any roadwork. I just thought Google maps was wrong, it showed roadwork pretty much the full lenght of the road from Prague to Brno.

Answer (score 7):

Busy - it depends on a day. Friday is bad, everybody gets out of Prague for weekend. There is a reconstruction taking place and you can expect traffic jams.

I like [Rodos.vsb.cz](http://rodos.vsb.cz/Road.aspx?road=D1_1) service, it shows you traffic information in real time. It is better than Waze as it uses sensors inside the road.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you! So what am I looking at? I think I understand some of it but what does the "LoS" mean? Why are some numbers in delay in green/yellow/red, it does not seem to be red = more delay? We will be driving the route on monday morning. That is one very nice page! I wish we would have something like it here.

Comment: Found the documentation, so I can use google translate.

Comment: You can switch the language at top of the page.

Comment: I read just two values - an average speed and a delay. These are important.

Comment: Yes you can choose english but the help is sitll in czech. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 6):

Now we are back at the campsite after driving Prague->Brno->Prague and it was not as bad as I imagined.
If we had this many road works in Sweden there would be a serious delay and some complete standstills. But here the trafic just moved along as it's supposed to.
I'm impressed.

Answer (score 3):

Google Maps (https://www.google.cz/maps) navigation works very well in estimating the traffic on **D1**. Even ahead of time you can check the route, set date and time and it gives you reasonable estimates (i.e. 2h10m, 2h40m with usual traffic). If you have mobile-data, use it online while on the road to get alternative routes in case of unexpected accident-related traffic jams. Waze (https://www.waze.com/) also works well.

Comment: We did not have mobile data when we where there. We usually buy a prepaid simcard with mobile data, but we didn't this time. Last time I did it was in Norway last year and the simcard got jammed in the simcard holder and destroyed my phone :-/ But thank you for the suggestion :-)

Comment: You can use wifi at McDonals or anywhere else or even check few days ahead of time if you set the exact date in navigation UI (definitely available  on desktop, not sure about mobile app). Happy travelling ;)